# Can I have a .NET app.config file reside outside of application directory

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, configuration

I am struggling with a clients requirements that the windows form app i'm writing will be installed to C:\program files\xxx and will be run under an account which will not have write privs to the c:\program files\xxx directory.  So this means that my configuration files need to live in another location so users can make manual changes to them and my app can make changes to them.

I am not finding anyway to do this?  I was hoping I could use configSource but this has limitations that the external config files should be at the same relative physical path as the application as well which does me no good.  The appSettings file attribute would work, but that is only for that config section.  I make use of other config sections like connection strings and system.serviceModel.  Any thoughts on what my options are here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't the account have write permissions *just* to your app.config?

Comment: App.config are designed to be readonly at runtime.  I recommend you store this user data in a different directory with approrpriate permissions.  Or use Impersonation if you have to.

Comment: aquinas, wish we could, that makes the most sense to me, but it is a government client with odd requirements around security.  P. Brian, it is not really "user" data per say, these are application settings that after installation will need to be tweaked.

Answer (score 5):

The [Applications Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) framework handles user-scoped settings automatically.

You can place your *default* settings in the `app.Config` file, and provide a mechanism (within your program) to edit the settings. Any edits will automatically get written into a user-specific settings file in the *user's documents folder* (where they have write permissions) for you.  There is no need to have the actual `app.Config` be writable directly by each user.

Just include the "writable" settings default values within the `<userSettings>` element, and the framework will take care of it for you, following the correct Windows guidelines for where to write everything.

Comment: Reed, I think that the issue with this is that these are not user settings.  These are things like the database connections used, the ports that the services should listen on and that sort of thing.  They can be customized after the application is installed, but as I understand the config file will not be writable by the application since they will have the directory it is installed locked down. They want the config in another directory that can be edited.  Not sure why it is this way, but that is what they have requested!

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
    private static XmlDocument loadConfigDocument()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = null;
        try
        {
            doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(getConfigFilePath());
            return doc;
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new Exception("No configuration file found.", e);
        }
    }

    private static string getConfigFilePath()
    {
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config";
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this just load the configuration file that is in the same directory as the exe?  this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Could you not change what `getConfigFilePath()` returns to make it read a config from a different location.